# Error response from daemon: No such image latest

Tags: docker, github-actions

Github workflow returns this following error: `Error response from daemon: No such image: ghcr.io/organization-project-website/controller:latest.` But still pushes my docker image to the registry. Which I find weird.

Here's my yml file. Where the problem happens:

```
  - name: Extract version for controller
    id: extract_version_controller
    if: steps.changed-files-controller.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
    uses: Saionaro/extract-package-version@v1.1.1
    with:
      path: ./controller
  - name: Pushing controller image
    if: steps.changed-files-controller.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
    run: |
      docker tag ${{ env.image_name_controller }} ${{ env.tag }}
      docker push ${{ env.tag }}
      docker push ${{ env.image_name_controller }}:latest
    env:
      tag: ${{ env.image_name_controller }}:v${{ steps.extract_version_controller.outputs.version }}.${{ github.run_number }}
```

Comment: You push it twice and the first one probably works? For the second, you might need to first tag it with `latest`.